# Find connection string for DB in Rider/Azure Data Studio. SQL

Tags: sql-server, docker, connection-string, rider, azure-data-studio

I created server through docker with command:

`docker run -d — name MySQLServer -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=your_password123’ -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge`

I'm working on an M1 Mac, and everything works fine. I created test DB and tables. Studio for visualization of my server I use Rider or Azure Data Studio. Both of them are friendly using but I can't get connection string for my DB from both of them. I need it for appSettings in my .NET project. How I can find it? In Visual Studio I found it in properties of DB. Here I don't see such option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am also using M1 Mac and SQL Edge coming from [this tutorial](https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-an-m1-mac-arm64/).
In the ASP.NET WebApp the connection string looks something like this:

```
      "ConnectionStrings": {
          "Default": "Server=localhost; Database=<insert db name>; User Id=sa; Password=your_password123"
      }
```

Comment: If you are getting this error with the previous connection string:
`System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.`

It is because by default Encrypt is set to True, so you will need to add this to the connection string: **Encrypt=False** or **TrustServerCertificate=true**.

For more information visit this
[issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1402)